# Convert Method to LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, .net-6.0

I have a validation function that receives two strings and makes a count compare, if the strings are the same size then it checks if the visible characters in the first string are the same as the second string.

```
private bool ValidateEncryptedText(string encrypted, string plain)
{
    if (plain.Count() != encrypted.Count())
        return false;
    else
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < plain.Count(); index++)
        {
            if (plain[index] != '*' && plain[index] != encrypted[index])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `string.Length` instead of `Count()`, and using `Zip` to compare pairs, projecting to value tuples to avoid creating a lot of objects:

```cs
private bool ValidateEncryptedText(string encrypted, string plain) =>
    plain.Length == encrypted.Length &&
    plain.Zip(encrypted, (p, e) => ((p, e)))
         .All(pair => pair.p == '*' || pair.p == pair.e);
```

Note that by using `All` instead of counting the failures, we can return as soon as we find a difference. (It also makes the intention clearer, in my view.)

I would note that the variable names are perhaps misleading here - it would be really odd for plaintext and encrypted text to be the same.

Comment: Wouldn't `.Any()` instead of `.All()` be faster as you return earlier when your statement is met (negated here).

Comment: @klekmek: `All` does that already.

Comment: Good to know, makes sense indeed.

Comment: Yup, this will be much better and the conditions are straight forword @jon-skeet

Comment: @jon-skeet 
About the naming should be maskedText, plainText
https://dotnetfiddle.net/JDUfXu

Comment: @esamaldinelzain: Right, that would make more sense. Please pay attention to using suitable names when asking questions; it makes questions easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The new syntax will be

```
private bool ValidateEncryptedText(string encrypted, string plain) => plain.Count() != encrypted.Count() ? false : !(plain.Where((c, index) => c != '*' && c != encrypted[index]).Count() > 0);
```